# android unlock screen using nfc

Tags: android, screen, nfc, unlock

I want to unlock the andorid screen when a tag is detected - based on the tag ID.

something like how com.biwota.cerbero is done. someone here has any experience or knows how this can be done. ? could you please point to the right directions perhaps ?

thank you
Domnic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, unfortunately. NFC polling is turned off when the screen is off or locked, since Android 4.0 ICS. Only with a custom ROM you can modify this behaviour.

Comment: But com.biwota.cerbero is an app that one can download and use from the google play. How can that be possible without a custom ROM ?  You mean to say that this app will not work after android 4.0 ? means.. not upwards compatible ?

Comment: I just installed the app to try it out. It shows its special NFC unlock screen only *after* the Android unlock screen on my phone.

Comment: Hello NFC Guy, Thank you for verifying this. I tried this too. The app locks the phone after the basic lock from the DevicePolicyManager's admin task. I did a test code to check this. NFC Service is actually disabled when the phone is locked. Hence scanning cannot be done.

Comment: This app com.biwota.cerbero.. does the following.. when the NFC tag is used to lock the screen, Once the Android Unlock screen is cleared, then comes this special NFC unlock screen. When this screen is visible - pressing the HOME button actually closes the app. How can one detect a HOME key code in an app ?... do you have an idea ?